# python web-based automation tool that can use multiple tabs or windows at the same time

Tags: python, selenium

I have been using selenium on python and was trying to see if there was a way to make multiple requests function at the same time. For example having running a few different google searches at the same time either on different tabs or on separate windows. Is there a way to do this on selenium? If not is there a different way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple Selenium sessions and set each one to run on a separate thread which will allow you to run multiple searches at the same time.

For example:

```
import thread

def someFunction():
    # Your selenium code here

def someFunction2():
    # Your selenium code here


thread.start_new_thread(someFunction, ())
thread.start_new_thread(someFunction2, ())
```